# Struct object initialize with not needed object

Tags: swift, struct

I have the following ClassRoom Struct

```
struct ClassRoom: Codable {
  let name: String
  let classId: String
  let date: String
}
```

While I am forming a `ClassRoom` object, I do not need `date` object.
// do not need date object here!,

```
let classRoom = ClassRoom(name: "Math", classId: "12343")
```

> ```
>  Missing argument for parameter 'date' in call
> ```

But I need `date` object when I decode the `ClassRoom`.

Comment: Make it optional.

Comment: It is still complaining      Missing argument for parameter 'date' in call

Comment: I think it needs to be defaulted to `nil`, and made mutable: `var date: String? = nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `date` be optional.

Two approaches:

You can keep using the compiler synthesized memberwise initializer. For it to use `nil` as a default value, you need to make the `date` variable mutable:

```swift
struct ClassRoom: Codable {
    let name: String
    let classId: String
    var date: String? = nil
}
```

If you want to keep it mutable, you'll have to add your own initializer, with a defaulted parameter, like so:

```swift
struct ClassRoom: Codable {
    let name: String
    let classId: String
    let date: String?
    
    init(name: String, classId: String, date: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.classId = classId
        self.date = date
    }
}
```